# is there any voice recognition software for Linux?

Tags: linux, voice-command

Its a little odd question . Am quite craze of voice recognition services in modern operating systems like windows 7 and later. Is there any linux altenative there? Am using kubuntu as my base os. Am waiting for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do not think there is a free and good one on linux right now, but you can check this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition_in_Linux

to see if anything would meet your need. you can always try to use wine to run windows programs, of which there are many.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the build in Google Doc function called Voice Typing **CTRL+Shift+S**:
[image: Google Doc - Voice Typing]